Android Room Synchronous query
I'm using Room, and while I'm happy most of my queries are asynchronous, I have one query I need to be synchronous.
I can't seem to understand / implement suspend (even if that's correct).
Advice on how I can make one query synchronous would be great, as don't really want to use sqlite.
Activity: Query that needs to be synchronous
Favourite fave = appDb.favouriteDao().findByTitle(formTitleText);

DAO:
@Dao
public interface FavouriteDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM favourite")
    List<Favourite> getAll();

    @Insert
    void insertFavourite(Favourite favourite);

    @Update
    void updateFavourite(Favourite favourite);

    @Delete
    void delete(Favourite favourite);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM favourite WHERE calc_title LIKE :title LIMIT 1")
    Favourite findByTitle(String title);

    @Query("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM favourite WHERE calc_title LIKE :title LIMIT 1)")
    boolean isRowIsExist(String title);

    @Query("UPDATE favourite SET fav_status = :value WHERE calc_title LIKE :title")
    void updateFavourite(String value, String title);
}

###UPDATE###
Code included as requested. Basically a Firestore query, with results saved to Calculators ArrayList. All the dataSection variable queried are added to the ArrayList with exception of the setFormFavourite. Hence why I thought this must be async (also all the info on Room I read seemed to suggest all Queries are asynchronous).
Regarding Suspend, not using Kotlin and would rather note. Simply mentioned it as saw this as a way to ensure Room query completion. However if my room query is synch then I'm lost why dataSection.setFormFavourite(fave.getFav()); not returning before final calculators.add(dataSection); called. It's not even added as 'null', simply not added. Log.d of fave.getFav() (placed directly after query) seems to return correctly.
Any help appreciated
private void getCalculators(Source path) {
        db.collection("Calculators")
                .get(path)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {

                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                String formTitleText = (document.getString("title"));
                                String formTagLine = (document.getString("tagLine"));
                                String numberOfFields = (document.getString("NumberFields"));
                                String formInfo = (document.getString("formInfo"));
                                String formRef = (document.getString("formRef"));
                                String formula = (document.getString("formula"));
                                String resultUnits = (document.getString("resultUnits"));
                                String formSections = (document.getString("sections"));

                                Calculators dataSection = new Calculators();
                                dataSection.setFormTitleText(formTitleText);
                                dataSection.setFormTagLine(formTagLine);
                                dataSection.setNumberOfFields(numberOfFields);
                                dataSection.setFormInfo(formInfo);
                                dataSection.setFormRef(formRef);
                                dataSection.setFormula(formula);
                                dataSection.setResultUnits(resultUnits);
                                dataSection.setFormSections(formSections);

                                // add favourite status to room db
                                Favourite fave = appDb.favouriteDao().findByTitle(formTitleText);
                                 dataSection.setFormFavourite(fave.getFav());
                                
                                calculators.add(dataSection);


"while I'm happy most of my queries are asynchronous" -- all of the ones in your DAO are synchronous, not asynchronous. "Advice on how I can make one query synchronous would be great" -- you already have this, for all of your DAO methods.

Really? My query is not being completed in a synchronous manner. The code immediately post my query is run before the result of the query has returned. I’m using the query result to then get a variable from the entity returned by my query and adding the result to an array, but as it seems to be querying synchronously, the array is being completed prior to the DAO query has returned, thus before I can get the variable from the entity. Surely if they we’re synchronous, then the retuned entity and its variable would be back prior to array completion?

*queried asynchronously

"My query is not being completed in a synchronous manner" -- at the level of the DAO, it is. We cannot comment on code that is not in your question. So, for example, when you call getAll(), the database operation executes, and getAll() returns the actual database result, in the form of your entity objects. Since you are programming in Java, an asynchronous form of your DAO would have getAll() return Single<List<Favorite>> (using RxJava) or LiveData<List<Favorite>> or whatever else Room supports for asynchronous Java DAO methods nowadays.

FWIW, I cover using reactive frameworks with Room in this chapter of this free book. This book's samples are in Kotlin, so the coroutines option covered there will not be available to you for your Java code. And, this book is a few years old at this point, and so Room probably has evolved some in that time.

findByTitle runs synchronously. It blocks the execution of the rest of the code until it is done. Then it returns a Favourite object, and then the rest of your code is executed. Please [edit] your question and add a [mre] that demonstrates the undesired behavior. Also, since you mentioned suspend: This is a feature only available in Kotlin, you use Java though, so that is not an option unless you want to migrate to Kotlin. Please specify if you want answers for Java or Kotlin.

@CommonsWare appreciate the replies. Will look at the book (aware Kotlin). I have updated my question, hopefully more obvious where my fault lies

Forget about it, because it will cause an IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread. Asynchronous operation is being enforced by Room. If it has to be, you cannot use Room to do so.

@MartinZeitler Thanks for reply, however not entirely true, as I've add .allowMainThreadQueries() As I'm only querying once, I felt it was safe to use as any delay wouldn't be an issue. You also mention Asynch is enforced by Room, which I thought .allowMainThreadQueries() changed, but also replies above that that it is synch

Am I going to have to use Sqlite to have persistent data for what I'm trying to achieve?

allowMainThreadQueries() does not exist anymore; just handle it with Executor. Or directly access the underlying database with SQLiteOpenHelper, where one has to manually map the record-sets to data-model, because there is no ORM given (which is the beauty of Room).
